# WPF: In a spreadsheet-like application, how to detect whether my model properties are undefined as opposed to zero?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding, datagrid

My application performs a **Calculation Chain**. If any of the fields is empty, the calculations of any field that depends on it should not be performed. My problem is to distinguish a number-holding TextBox field that has not been touched (ie holds and undefined value) from one having a zero value.

I guess this problem is similar to **nullable** Booleans and nullable types. Are there "Nullable Doubles"?

If my app were based on the GUI TextBoxes, an empty string would indicate an Undefined value. However, WPF Gurus keep on telling us: "Do NOT manipulate the GUI controls/widgets, only the models bound to them!!!".

TIA

Comment: Think about it in the following terms: `"how would my application need to be structured, if instead of a GUI there was an external Web Service operating against my data?"` Think of it as if there were NO UI at all, and that will help you come up with a proper structure, decoupled from the UI, which is still able to perform your business logic, even though there is no UI. Then just hook the UI to the existing working functionality via DataBinding.

Comment: I suppose that `DataGrid` and `TextBox` deal correctly with this? If I assign: "undefined" to some value, its corresponding bound GUI field should show empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess this problem is similar to nullable Booleans and nullable types. Are there "Nullable Doubles"?

Of course -- this is the only correct way.  Use `double?` for your doubles that may or may not be set.

Nullable variables also have some nice supporting features in XAML and C#:

- You can use the `TargetNullValue` in a binding to display some boilerplate text for unset values.
- You can do arithmetic on two `double?` values, and if one of them is null, then the result will also be null.
- It's easy to apply a default values, using the null-coalescing operator

Comment: "+1. And +1 again.": As they say in politics: "Vote early, vote *often*"   :-)

Comment: I just discovered that none other than **Excel** deals incorrectly with this issue...